# moving the Yeoman office SSO client secret

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, yeoman, outlook-web-addins

I am developing an outlook add-in using the Yeoman Office generator (Office Add-in Task Pane project supporting single sign-on).

All documentation on using this program says to run "npm run configure-sso" after Yeoman has finished and it builds the AAD instance for you.

My problem is "npm run configure-sso" saves the client secret in Microsoft's Credential Manager (on the PC), but I want to host my add-in on Azure. Is there a way to move the client secret from Credential Manager into an Azure instance, or into an environment variable in the add-in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This setup likely won't work on Azure deployment because `office-addin-sso` package SSO code is attempting to store and get the app secret in Windows credential manager so you have to remove that package and then add the code yourself to handle SSO so that you can deploy to Azure.

Here are some [workaround](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-NodeJS-SSO/issues/61#issuecomment-821517972) . However, Microsoft team have plan to document this sometime in August, so hopefully will have guidance around this soon.